# Chef - Foodcritic FC019 false positive

Tags: chef-infra

We are using foodcritic to lint all of our chef cookbooks and have recently come across this problem.

Using foodcritic 6.3.0

Output of `foodcritic .` is

```
FC019: Access node attributes in a consistent manner: ./recipes/configure_topics.rb:6
FC019: Access node attributes in a consistent manner: ./recipes/configure_topics.rb:10
FC019: Access node attributes in a consistent manner: ./recipes/configure_topics.rb:12
```

configure_topics.rb has the following contents

```
#
# Cookbook Name:: kafka
# Recipe:: configure_topics
#

node['kafka']['topics'].each do |topic, flag|
    bash "create #{topic} topic" do
        user "root"
        code <<-EOH
        /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper #{node['kafka']['broker']['zookeeper']['connect']} --create --topic #{topic} --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1
        EOH
        not_if "/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper #{node['kafka']['broker']['zookeeper']['connect']} --list | grep #{topic}"
    end
end
```

As seen in the code, the symbol method of accessing attributes is not used, so FC019 should not be shown here, correct?

I've opened the following issue with foodcritic on their github [here](https://github.com/acrmp/foodcritic/issues/474), however I haven't heard back.

Is there anything I can do to change my recipe so it doesn't throw these warnings in the interim? Thanks.

Comment: You can disable particular warnings on a per-line basis (just add `~FC019` to the end of affected lines). Does that work?

Comment: Are there other files in the same cookbook using symbols for attributes?

Comment: @KarenB, that was indeed the issue. My attributes default file was using the dot notation `default.kafka.version` for example. Once I fixed all of those to use the string notation the warning went away. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @KarenB aluded to, the check is against [the entire cookbook](https://github.com/acrmp/foodcritic/blob/master/lib/foodcritic/rules.rb#L260). You are likely using one of the other formats for everything else in the cookbook, so those were flagged as the least used and thus an error.

Comment: As I said in response to @KarenB, this was the issue. The attributes default file was using dot notation. Thanks!